# How can I simulate a C++ union in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, struct, unions

I have a small question about structures with the `LayoutKind.Explicit` attribute set. I declared the `struct` as you can see, with a `fieldTotal` with 64 bits, being `fieldFirst` the first 32 bytes and `fieldSecond` the last 32 bytes. After setting both `fieldfirst` and `fieldSecond` to `Int32.MaxValue`, I'd expect `fieldTotal` to be `Int64.MaxValue`, which actually doesn't happen. Why is this? I know C# does not really support C++ unions, maybe it will only read the values well when interoping, but when we try to set the values ourselves it simply won't handle it really well?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct STRUCT {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int64 fieldTotal;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32 fieldFirst;

    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public Int32 fieldSecond;
}

        STRUCT str = new STRUCT();
        str.fieldFirst = Int32.MaxValue;
        str.fieldSecond = Int32.MaxValue;
        Console.WriteLine(str.fieldTotal); // <----- I'd expect both these values
        Console.WriteLine(Int64.MaxValue); // <----- to be the same.
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that FieldOffsetAttribute takes a number of bytes as parameter -- not number of bits. This works as expected:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct STRUCT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int64 fieldTotal;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32 fieldFirst;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public Int32 fieldSecond;
}
```

Comment: Plus what Reed & Jared say about signed vs. unsigned.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the hex values if Int32.MaxValue and Int64.MaxValue should provide the answer.

The key is the most significant bit.  For a positive integer, the most significant bit is only set for a negative number.  So the max value of Int32 is a 0 followed by a whole series of 1s.  The order is unimportant, just that there will be at least a single 0 bit.  The same is true of Int64.MaxValue.

Now consider how a union should work.  It will essentially lay out the bits of the values next to one another.  So now you have a set of bits 64 in length which contains two 0 bit values.  One for each of the Int32.MaxValue instances.  This cannot ever be equal to Int64.MaxValue since it can contain only a single 0 bit.

Oddly enough you will probably get the behavior you are looking for if you set fieldSecond to Int32.MinValue.

**EDIT** Missed that you need to make it FieldOffset(4) as well.

Answer (score 5):

[Ben M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162262/how-can-i-simulate-a-c-union-in-c/1162291#1162291) provided one of the more important elements - your definition is not setup correctly.

That being said, this won't work - even in C++ with a union.  The values you specified won't be (and shouldn't be) the same values, since you're using signed (not unsigned) ints.  With a signed int (Int32), you're going to have a 0 bit followed by 1 bits.  When you do the union, you'll end up with a 0 bit, followed by a bunch of 1 bits, then another 0 bit, then a bunch of 1 bits... The second 0 bit is what's messing you up.

If you used UInt32/UInt64, this would work property, since the extra sign bit doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With what you said and Ben said, it works as expected. Thanks!